# Is there anyway to modify thickness & color of a selected polygon?

Tags: qgis

QGIS - version 1.8.0.  Is there anyway to modify the thickness and color of a selected polygon (Select Single Feature)?

Comment: the selected polygons appear in yellow color..you want to change that?

Comment: The outline is a very faint yellow, I'm wanting to make the line thicker and in something like red, etc..

Comment: why not save that selected polygon to an individual layer. But yes would be nice to know if each polygon in a layer could have different properties.

Comment: You can always add another attribute field to the attribute table just for coloring, and set the style to `categorized` by that field.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open `Settings -> Options` In the General Tab, there should be a
   selection color with a yellowish button. Click and change that to
   your required color.
2. Restart Qgis to see it in effect

Comment: You can also set this for an individual project by Opening `Settings -> Project Settings`, General Tab. No need to restart in this case.

Comment: This does not answer the entire question - how can the thickness of the selection symbol outline be changed?