# Making selected lines thicker to see overlapped features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a bunch of overlapped lines. Some of the shorter ones are covered by others and are difficult to see. I am trying to see those lines by highlighting them via selection in the attribute table. However, the line in selection isn't wide enough to be visible from beneath. I can only see the selection if the selected feature is on the top.

**My Question:**

Is there a way to make the selected line thicker in QGIS (QGIS3)?

Related questions/answers here at GIS either do not address the thickness issue, or evolve coding and/or changing the line shape, which seems to be an overkill here:

[Is there anyway to modify thickness & color of a selected polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54574/)

[Representing overlapping polylines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140685/)

[Shifting display of overlapping lines in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239129/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In QGIS 3, you can use the Rule-based Symbology by

- going to the layer's `properties -> Symbology`,
- change the type on the top to `Rule-based`
- click the "Add" (`+`) button and add a new rule with the condition `is_selected() = True` as the `Filter`
- change the line style for this rule to have a different thickness (or color) as in the figure below:

[image: new symbology rule]

Comment: That works, though it does seem to slow down rendering noticeably, at least with large contour datasets.

Comment: The color still remains yellow. To change that, go to Project → Properties → General → Selection Color

Answer (score 3):

If you install the Plugin "Expressions Plus"
you have access to an *isselected()* fonction

Then you can use the data defined property to style your layer

for the thickness you can use :

CASE  WHEN isselected( 'LAYER_NAME' )='true' THEN 5 ELSE 0.5 END

this will give you a thicker selection....

Edit : the Plugin "Expressions Plus" is not available for 2.99 but there is a *is_selected()* fonction already in 2.99 so no plugin needed for qgis 3.0