# QGIS - make selected hidden objects visible

Tags: qgis, symbology, overlapping-features, visibility, select

Selected objects in QGIS are not visible as selected (i.e. not visible with standard colour yellow) if they are covered by overlaying objects.

This is the case for objects in underlaying layers as well as for underlaying objects within the same layer.

Is there another approach than [rule-based symbology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255984/making-selected-lines-thicker-to-see-overlapped-features-in-qgis) to make underlaying selected objects visible? I want to preserve the categorized symbology.

I am using QGIS, version 3.4.15.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this problem using the option *Control feature rendering order*.

In *Symbology*, using or not the option Categorised, select the option *Layer Rendering > Control feature rendering order*.

[image]

Here you can use a simple expression to control the order of rendering and to make the selected feature rendered on top of all the others.

This is the expression to use:

```
if (is_selected( ) , 100, 0)
```

[image]

Now you will see the selected feature on top of all the others.

[image]

Comment: You can just use: "if (is_selected( ) , 100, 0)" in case you don't want to influence the rendering order except for selected features.

Comment: Good point. I will correct with your suggestion. Thanks.